# Inserting date in a database using PreparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, prepared-statement, java.util.date

I have a form which captures a date that the user input in a JFormattedTextField. Then the Date need to be stored in a database (postgresql) using PreparedStatement. I am having error messages at the line pStat.setDate(4, dob);.

```
 Date dob = (Date)ftxtDOB.getValue();
       String add = txtAddress.getText();
       String country = txtCountry.getText();
       try {
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "postgres","cisco");

           pStat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer_info VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           pStat.setString(1, id);
           pStat.setString(2, surname);
           pStat.setString(3, fName);
           pStat.setDate(4, dob);
       }catch(Exception e){

       }
```

Edit: I have this error message from the compiler.

```
no suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date)
    method java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,java.util.Calendar) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date by method invocation conversion)
```

Edit: SOLVED, I used:

```
    pStat.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(dob.getTime()));
```

Comment: And what error messages might that be? You should really fill out that catch clause... at least put a e.printStackTrace() in there.

Comment: And the error is? Have you read the error message? It's supposed to help you, and is not some random gibberish that can be ignored. NEVER ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What error message?

Guessing that it's actually a compiler error message, are you sure you are using `java.sql.Date` and not `java.util.Date`?

Edit: As you edited question, yes you will need `new java.sql.Date(date.getTime())` or something (data handling in Java is a mess! (at the moment)).

Comment: I used    pStat.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(dob.getTime())); and it worked. Thank you.